# Deleting large no of files on linux eats up CPU

Tags: linux, files

I generate more than 50GB of cache files on my RHEL server (and typical file size is 200kb so no of files is huge). When I try to delete these files it takes 8-10 hours.

However, the bigger issue is that the system load goes to critical for these 8-10 hours. Is there anyway where I can keep the system load under control during the deletion.

I tried using

```
nice -n19 rm -rf *
```

but that doesn't help in system load.

P.S. I asked the same question on [superuser.com](https://superuser.com/questions/124707/deleting-large-no-of-files-on-linux-eats-up-cpu) but didn't get a good enough answer so trying here.

Comment: What kind of disk subsystem, what other load is on this filesystem at the same time?

Comment: Its and ext3 filesystem. Lots of disk reads happen on it as it contains a file based cache.

Comment: The cache files are spread out over several directories so each directory does not contain more than say 100 files?  As opposed to them all being placed in the same folder, which may incur a lot of unnecessary overhead including locking the directory when deleting files?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here are some [benchmarks](http://linuxgazette.net/102/piszcz.html) for various operations and filesystems for your reference. (On a busy system of course you would have different results, but hopefully this will give you an idea of what to expect).

If I would be in your chair I would try to get a baseline benchmark of the scenario:

- establish how long the operation would take on bare hardware isolated of everything else (and yes, it should take much, much less then 7-8 hours even on pretty old hardware).
- try to add other operations that typically occur in a controlled manner and see what actually makes it run so long

Some numbers.

On 5 year old notebook, 
**ext3** mounted rw, noatime, running top and nothing much more
create 10k directories with shell script create10kdirs.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in $(seq 10000)
do
    mkdir $i
done
```

sudo time ./create10kdirs.sh
24.59user
20.70system
0:47.04elapsed
96%CPU (0avgtext+0avgdata 0maxresident)k80inputs+8outputs (1major+2735150minor)pagefaults 0swaps

delete 10k directories with 
sudo time rm -rf
0.10user
19.75system
0:20.71elapsed
95%CPU (0avgtext+0avgdata 0maxresident)k0inputs+8outputs (0major+222minor)pagefaults 0swaps

same hardware, **ext4** mounted rw, noatime
create 10k directories with shell script
sudo time create10kdirs.sh
23.96user
22.31system
0:49.26elapsed
93%CPU (0avgtext+0avgdata0maxresident)k1896inputs+8outputs(20major+2715174minor)pagefaults 0swaps

delete 10k directories with 
sudo time rm -rf
0.13user
16.96system
0:28.21elapsed
60%CPU (0avgtext+0avgdata0maxresident)k10160inputs+0outputs(1major+219minor)pagefaults0swaps

4 year old notebook, **xfs** mounted rw,relatime,nobarrier on USB
sudo time create10kdirs.sh
14.19user
13.86system
0:29.75elapsed
94%CPU (0avgtext+0avgdata0maxresident)k432inputs+0outputs(1major+2735243minor)pagefaults 0swaps

delete 10k directories with
sudo time rm -rf
0.13user
2.65system
**0:08.20elapsed**
**33%CPU** (0avgtext+0avgdata 0maxresident)k120inputs+0outputs (1major+222minor)pagefaults 0swaps

Conclusion:
This old hardware would erase 400k small files+folders on ext3 in approx 21s * 40 = 12m40s. On xfs (with nobarriers) it would do it in approx 5m20s.
Granted in both test cases the test machine was not under heavy load, but to me it seems that your problems are not strictly related to your choice of filesystem.

EDIT2
Also, after running above benchmarks I went to try the delete with 
find . -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -delete

and the results!:

ext3
delete 10k directories with 
sudo time find . -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -delete
0.04user
0.44system
**0:00.88elapsed**
55%CPU (0avgtext+0avgdata 0maxresident)k516inputs+8outputs(1major+688minor)pagefaults0swaps

ext4
delete 10k directories with
sudo time find . -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -delete
0.05user
0.66system
**0:01.02elapsed**
70%CPU (0avgtext+0avgdata 0maxresident)k568inputs+0outputs (1major+689minor)pagefaults swaps

xfs
delete 10k directories with
sudo time find . -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -delete
0.06user
0.84system
0:04.55elapsed
19%CPU (0avgtext+0avgdata 0maxresident)k416inputs+0outputs (3major+685minor)pagefaults 0swaps

Real conclusion is that rm -rf is not very clever and that it'll under-perform for big trees. (providing that my test case is really representative).

Note: I also tested xargs variant and it is fast, but not as fast as the above.

Comment: As per the benchmarks link you mentioned, it seems like ext3 takes a real performance hit when deleting lots of directories. My cache has lots of files as well as directories. That may be one of the reasons why it is so slow.

Comment: +1 explains the question with supporting data.

Answer (score 5):

As you mentioned in a comment, you are using `ext3`.

It is well known that `rm` performance for large files on ext3 is poor; it is one of the things which were fixed in `ext4`. See for instance [this post](http://www.phoronix.com/forums/showpost.php?p=80150&postcount=25), or [kernelnewbies](http://kernelnewbies.org/Ext4) (which mentions extents improve delete and truncate speeds for large files).

I do not know how much that applies to your typical file sizes. I would it expect it to apply at least a little, since with around 200kB you would already be using indirect blocks on `ext3`, versus possibly a single extent on `ext4`.

---

As a workaround (since you probably will not upgrade to `ext4` just for that), delete only a few files each time and add a `sleep` between the deletions. It is not pretty, but should help reducing the load.

Also, if losing the files on power loss is not a problem (since it is a cache of some sort), you could put them in a separate partition which you `mkfs` again on boot, and use `ext3` without a journal or even `ext2`. The cause for the high load is probably the journal being flushed to disk conflicting with the reads (you mentioned in another post that you have lots of concurrent reads).

Answer (score 3):

Maybe the shell is the cause of the problem. You should use directly find : `find /dir -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -delete`

Comment: how did you know that this could be a reason for such high gain?

Answer (score 2):

This may or may not be related: but I have had occasions where `rm` could not handle the number of files I provided it on the command line (through the star operator). Instead I would use the following command from the shell:

```
for i in *; do rm -rf $i; done
```

In this case you could be deleting trees in which case the above may not do what you need. You might have to split up the delete operation into parts, e.g.

```
for i in [a-mA-M]*; do rm -rf $i; done
for i in [n-zN-Z]*; do rm -rf $i; done
```

Comment: I do rm -rf <dir> and it works. My issue is with the time and CPU it takes. 
I need something which is less CPU intensive.

Comment: My point is that `rm` might work quicker when it doesn't have to juggle so many files in memory. Dom's answer might be most appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

That's only 250,000 files or so, shouldn't be a problem really - what file system are you using and is this volume used for anything else?

Comment: Its an ext3 filesystem. Lots of disk reads are happening on this disk and it contains a file based cache. 
Are you saying the file deletions of this number should not take 7-8 hours?

Comment: I am saying exactly that, ext3 should be much quicker than this, have you considered putting these files onto a dedicated file system and retesting?

Comment: Considering the data is taking so much time to delete, the time to tar and transfer to another disk would be huge too (Its a remote server).
I don't think I have the resources to copy this data into another disk and check disk operations on that.

Comment: Sorry, that's not what I meant, I meant creating a new FS and creating your new files on that new FS in the first place, not moving existing ones.

Answer (score 1):

When you have a lot of files like you described you are invoking the command each time. Also you have to keep in mind on journaled FS you're dealing with buffer hits and metadata which can greatly impact  process times.

Your best bet is to use the find command like mentioned above only with a less than obvious feature.

```
find / -name filename.* -exec /bin/rm -f '{}' \+
```

Basically the "+" is your friend. What this does is create the filenames in sets and invokes rm command once per set. That's pretty much the same as what 'xargs' does but you don't have to worry about the correct flags if on BSD/Linux.

Very curious how much that speeds it up for you. So reply back if you are still around. Good luck !

Answer (score 0):

After studying filesystem benchmarks I've choosen JFS as file store for my mythtv video files because file deletes are fast (and mythtv waits for the delete to finish, making the IO sluggish).

You could also invoke 'rm' through 'find' and 'xargs' instead of rm -rf. This might be faster:

```
find <dir> | xargs rm
```

Answer (score 0):

How about piping a list of those files to Perl and using its unlink function?

```
find <dir> | perl -nle 'unlink;'
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree that it shouldn't take that long, but depending on the underlying storage being used, it may be expected with the intensive reads. I think ultimately your best solution is to add additional disks and split up your activities amongst them. RAID could help in some scenarios if you go down that route. What does iostat tell you during these times? You could also use a for loop and wrap the 'rm' commands in 'time' to get some additional information.

Another possibility, depending on your setup and the application of course, but maybe you could make these cache files on a different partition and just format the drive periodically rather than remove the files? I think running mkfs would cut the time down considerably, but your application is going to be unavailable while that happens so it won't be ideal.

I also like the idea of cleaning them up more often. Say in cron you schedule something like this every hour:

find ./ -maxdepth 1 -type f -name "some pattern" -ctime +1 -exec rm -f {} \;

This would delete every file that is older than 24 hours, rather then trying to do them all at once.