# How do I delete a directory that has many subdirectories?

Tags: linux, rm

I have a directory with many subdirectories.  I tried doing

```
rm -rf mydirectory
```

but it was still running after 1 hour.  I have tried getting the number of subdirectories with

```
ls -l . | egrep -c '^-'
```

but it hasn't finished after 30 minutes.

Is there a faster way to recursively delete an entire directory?

Comment: How many files are in that directory?  If you have millions of files it will take a long time.  What does `df -i` show on that filesystem?  If you do have a large number of files there really isn't much you can do except wait.

Comment: Not a duplicate question but similar ones you probably ought to read: http://serverfault.com/questions/127221/deleting-large-no-of-files-on-linux-eats-up-cpu and http://serverfault.com/questions/183821/rm-on-a-directory-with-millions-of-files

Answer (score 2):

```
/usr/bin/find /mydir_with_many_subdirs -exec rm {} \;
```

you can also filter with

```
/usr/bin/find /mydir_with_many_subdirs -type f -exec rm {} \;  -- will delete all files
/usr/bin/find /mydir_with_many_subdirs -mtime +10 -exec rm {} \;  -- will delete dirs and files older then 10
```

man find will give away more filters that you can apply.

Comment: This is going to take an ungodly amount of time. Either replace that `\;` with a `+` if you're running a recent version of GNU findutils, or `-print0` and pipe it to `xargs -0` if you're not.

Comment: in that case you can just use /usr/bin/find /my_dir -delete  (of course you can still apply filters for time, access etc)

Answer (score 0):

This should work, but I wouldn't use the -f option. Nor would I want to run that command as root! If there are any symlinks that link back to say, /var/log or /usr/lib, then you will run into trouble faster than you can say "OMGWTF!"

Which is likely also the problem that you're running into here - there are symlinks that either go to very large directories, or symlinks that go into some kind of infinite loop. It shouldn't take that long to remove a small directory that doesn't have much to recurse to.

Comment: I am not root on this machine.  Is there a solution to the symlink issue you describe, or a way to see if that's the case?

Comment: I am confused, 'man 7 symlink' says that "The  mv(1)  and  rm(1) commands do not follow symbolic links named as arguments, but respectively  attempt  to  rename  and  delete  them."

Comment: add a `-v` to your command to see what it's doing.  See if it's progressing at all.